# How to edit Magento product page template?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have just installed custom options for grouped products plugin. It currently generates the template in the product page below the add-to-cart button. Now if I need to position it above the add-to-cart button, what procedure should I need to follow?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with how "getChildHtml" works. The block is added in layout yet (because you see it), so you just need to edit your catalog/product/view.phtml and change the positioning of the actual `getChildHtml('block_name_in_layout_xml_you_want_to_move')`.